# GADInterstitial presentFromRootViewController causes current View Controller to close

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, admob, interstitial

I'm attempting to show a GADInterstitial ad when a user of my app clicks a certain button to go to a certain ViewController. In the new ViewController's viewDidLoad method I check to see if the GADInterstitial ad is ready, and if it is I attempt to present it. The problem is, when I dismiss the ad I notice that the ViewController that presented the ad is no longer there and instead it has sent me back to the ViewController that launched the ViewController that presented the ad.

Here's my code:

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


BTRInterstitialHelper *helper = [BTRInterstitialHelper sharedHelper];
if([helper isInterstitialReady]) {
    [helper.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```

My helper method just looks like this:

```
    -(BOOL)isInterstitialReady {
if ([self.interstitial isReady]) {
    return YES;
} else {
    return NO;
}
 }
```

I do notice thought that when I present the ad, this message shows up in the logs:

```
  Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged BTRIndividualLocationViewController: 0x7fd63bcd9c00.
```

Same problem occurs if I try to present it in viewWillAppear.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**
I have also tried the following, to try to pass in my app's actual rootViewController:

```
     UINavigationController *nav=(UINavigationController *)((BTRAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).window.rootViewController;
    UIViewController *rootController=(UIViewController *)[nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

    [helper.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:rootController];
```

Still the same result though, except that message doesn't pop up in the logs.

Comment: Maybe just do all of the interstitial stuff in the VC you want to actually show it. Use NSUserdefaults, when user presses button set a value to NSUserdefaults, in the VC where you want to show the interstitial check for that value of that NSUserdefaults and if show the interstitial and when it s fired reset the value of the NSUserdefaults for the next time... !?

Comment: I mean, you even don t need the NSUserdefaults stuff, why you launch the interstitial in another VC where you don t want to show it?

Comment: You want to show that interstitial everytime that VC is shown? Or only if it comes from a special button? if that, use NSUserdefaults, but do the interstitial stuff in the VC where you want to show it and not in another.

Comment: I want to be in a VC (vc1) that has a button on it that launches another VC (vc2). Basically in the transition from vc1 to vc2 I want the ad to pop up. When you close the ad vc2 should be there waiting. All the code you see above is in vc2.

Comment: yes, so do all of the interstitial stuff in VC2. why you do it in VC1 ?

Comment: I am doing it all in vc2. I have no code at all to do with this in vc1. vc1 actually can be a bunch of different vcs, but they all lead to vc2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VC2.h

```
#import "GADInterstitial.h"
#import "GADInterstitialDelegate.h"
```

set delegate

```
@interface VC2 : UIViewController <GADInterstitialDelegate>
```

and a property

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) GADInterstitial *interstitial;
```

VC2.m
in viewdidappear

```
self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
self.interstitial.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-yourNumber";
self.interstitial.delegate = self;

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
```

for test ads in simulator

```
request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ];
```

coud also add location and keywords in the request (optional)

then do request

```
[self.interstitial loadRequest:request];
```

listen to delegate

```
-(void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)ad {

if ([self.interstitial isReady]) {


    [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
  }
}
```

If you want to show the interstitial only when pressed from a certain button use NSUserdefaults.

In VC1 when button pressed

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"yes" forKey:@"showInterstitial"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and wrap all the code for the interstitial in VC2 in viewdidappear in:

```
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"showInterstitial"] isEqualToString:@"yes"]) {

}
```

and add to -(void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)ad {

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"no" forKey:@"showInterstitial"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

p.s. you could also use a Bool for NSUserdefaults of course, I do use strings caus I had some errors with Bools, but Bools would be more correct I guess

Comment: I think I must have not been clear in my question, because I don't think you're understanding it. My question is not how to show the ad only in certain cases. My question is why is my view controller closing when I exit out of the ad?

Comment: oh ok, I guess it has to do with your helper class. why use helper class? you would use it for a shared banner singleton, but with interstitials there is no need for that !? Just use my code, it s a few lines and it will work... no need for that helper

Comment: and do it in viewdidappear, viewdidload is loaded only once, not everytime the view is shown

Comment: Actually, I just figured it out. It was some other funky stuff I had going on in a custom UIPageCotronller that was causing this to get closed. Thanks for the effort though and the tips. I'll still give you the accepted answer.

Comment: Yeah, I had a reason I thought I would need it when I started, but I can't even remember what that was now. I'll probably get rid of it.

Comment: Irrelevant answer. I'm having the same issue. When the Ad Appears, i press the cross to close the ad, and the View Controller closes.

Answer (score 0):

A very similar scenario for me in 2018.

My current ViewControllers look like this:

```
  ViewController 1
   -> ViewController 2 (via presentViewController:animated:completion)
    -> GADOInterstitialViewController (presentFromRootViewController:)
```

When GADOInterstitialViewController is dismissed via `rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose:`, ViewController 2 is instantly dismissed also.

A simple solution to this issue that I have figured out. Simply override ViewController 2 function `dismissViewControllerAnimated` like this:

```
 - (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion {

    if(self.presentedViewController != nil){
        [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
    } else {
        [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
    }
}
```

This code block checks if ViewController 2 has a presented view controller and dismisses it, if not then ViewController 2 gets dismissed.

This works perfectly in my case :)